# How do I add type and label to each FormGroups as they are defined in a FormBuilder?

Tags: angular, types, label, formbuilder, formgroups

In Mat Tables, you can do a lot of dynamic things.

I'd like to define the matColumnDef and input data type automatically from the Form that's feeding data into the table.

I can already get the column keys from the declaration of the form. If it's declared like this...

```
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        name   : ['', Validators.required],
        date  : ['', [Validators.required]],
        units: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

I can dynamically build the table with columns labels from the keys like this...

```
    Object.keys(this.sourceForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
        this.displayedColumns.push(key);
    });
```

and then in the HTML...

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
```

That all works. But, then I'd like to make the table editable, and would LOVE if each column  had a dynamic data 'type' and also (wish list) if they also had a little better label than the key variable name.

Is there some way to extend the creation of the form group to also include data types and labels? The following is wrong, I know, but it gives you the idea of what I am looking for...

```
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        name   : ['', {"type": "text", "label":"Name"}, [Validators.required],
        date: ['', {"type": "date", "label":"Date"}, [Validators.required]],
        units: ['', {"type": "number", "label":"Number of Units"}, Validators.required]
    });
```

I saw in other places you can use name, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: You can to have an **auxiliar** array of columns with property type and label and create the form **based** in this array. Then use the Array in your .html. I feel it's more "natural" this approach than extends a FormGroup

Comment: @Eliseo, wouldn't that approach unfortunately lose all the benefits built-in to the other material objects in the html? like formControlName for matNativeControl in a <select> widget? I don't mind switching to a columnsSchema array. That's in a lot of examples. It just seems redundant to create a hardcoded columnsSchema to go along with a dynamic FormGroup. If we did both, then we'd have to continually remember to update the columnsSchema whenever we added a new field. Hopefully, there's a simple way to use the FormGroup that I'm just ignorant to. Thanks.

Comment: I expanded my comment in an answer. You can create the formGroup using the columnSchema in a setter of the `@Input`

Answer (score 0):

I think in a kind of

```
cols=[{columnName:'name',type:'text',label:'Name'},
      {columnName:'date',type:'date',label:'Date'},
      {columnName:'units',type:'number',label:'Number of units'}
      ...]

cols:any[];
displayedColumns:string[];

form:FormGroup=new FormGroup({})

selectedIndex:number=-1;
@Input('cols') set _(salue:any[])
{
    this.cols=value;
    this.displayColumns=value.map(x=>x.columName)

    value.forEach(x=>{
       this.form.addControl(x.columnName,new FormControl());
    })
    
}
```

The .html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of cols">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>col.columnName</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let index=index">
       <ng-container *ngIf="index!=selectedIndex">
       {{element[col.columnName]}} 
       <ng-container>
       <ng-container *ngIf="index==selectedIndex">
          <input [formControlName]="col.columnName" [type]="col.type" col.type="number">
       </ng-container>
   </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;
              let index=index;"
      (click)="selectedIndex=index" 
   ></tr>
</table>
```